# Django registration profile

Tags: django, attributeerror, email-validation, django-custom-user

I am new in django. I would like to create registration profile. I found some code but it doesn´t work for me.  When I want to makemigrations I always get this error  **AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'user.User'**
I read that I could fix it with  **User = get_user_model()** but it looks it is doesn´t work for me.

My models.py

```
import random
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

User = get_user_model()


def code_generator(length=5):
    numbers = '0123456789'
    return ''.join(random.choice(numbers) for _ in range(length))


class RegistrationProfile(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(default=code_generator, max_length=5)
    user = models.OneToOneField(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='registration_profile', primary_key=True)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_registration_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        profile, created = RegistrationProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
        if created:
            profile.save()
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password
from .models import User


class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, validators=[validate_password])
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'password2', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'first_name': {'required': True},
            'last_name': {'required': True}
        }

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['password'] != attrs['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"password": "Password fields didn't match."})

        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name']
        )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

and views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

from .serializers import RegisterSerializer


class RegisterView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
```

In the end I would like to send code to email for validation. Any ideas how I could do it by most effective way?

Comment: Import:
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Change ref in models to this user and viola.

Comment: What do you mean with "ref in models"?

Comment: Remove: User = get_user_model()
and add  from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class RegistrationProfile(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(default=code_generator, max_length=5)
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='registration_profile')

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_registration_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        profile, created = RegistrationProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
        if created:
            profile.save()
```